# Msmtp does not understand `/etc/aliases`

Tags: sendmail, msmtp

I have configured my Debian server to use `msmtp` for sending mails. Current use case are for example sending a daily report from `logwatch` to my isp email.

`echo "$body" | mutt -s "$topic" -- "myisp@email.com"`

I have configured `msmtp` by means of a global `msmtprc` file located at `/etc/msmtprc`. Contents shown below.

The next thing I want to configure is that my email for my root account (e.g., output from crontabs) is sent to my isp email as well.

I have googled around and found, for example on the Arch wiki, that I should just configure my aliases. Which I have done so at the bottom of the msmtp configuration file.

However, after running `newaliases`, and trying to execute

```
echo test | mail -s "test message" root
```

I get the error

```
send-mail: /etc/aliases: line 2: invalid address 'postmaster'
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 78
```

I am unsure how I can fix this. The alias shown below is what was already present. I only added the gmail address.

I think I could just put a new aliases file but that might break other services that rely on this. I.e., I don't know what the proper way to fix this is.

## `/etc/aliases`

```
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: christphe, christophe.detroyer@gmail.com
```

## `/etc/msmtprc`

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# msmtp System Wide Configuration file
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# A system wide configuration is optional.
# If it exists, it usually defines a default account.
# This allows msmtp to be used like /usr/sbin/sendmail.

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Accounts
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

account isp
host mail.isp.net
port 587
from admin@isp.com
auth login
user admin@isp.com
password foobar
syslog LOG_MAIL

logfile /var/log/msmtp.log

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configurations
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Construct envelope-from addresses of the form "user@oursite.example".
#auto_from on
#maildomain fermmy.server

# Use TLS.
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Syslog logging with facility LOG_MAIL instead of the default LOG_USER.
# Must be done within "account" sub-section above
#syslog LOG_MAIL

# Set a default account
account default : isp

aliases /etc/aliases
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Comment: msmtp only accepts aliases of the form `root: christophe.detroyer@gmail.com` so I should create a `/etc/aliases.msmtp` with just that line for the moment and change your config. Is `mail` a link to `msmtp`? Do you have postfix or sendmail installed too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update 2019-10-17

msmtp version 1.8.6 (released 2019-09-27) now has native support for chained/recursive alias expansion in `/etc/aliases`.  See https://marlam.de/msmtp/news/msmtp-1-8-6/.

## Original Answer

So, I had the exact same issue when I migrated from ssmtp to msmtp.  The issue is caused by the [`is_address()` function in aliases.c](https://sources.debian.org/src/msmtp/1.8.3-1/src/aliases.c/#L90).  Basically, if the target of the alias doesn't contain `'@'`, msmtp thinks it's invalid and dies.  You can work around this by just appending @ to all the aliases that redirect to root.

In your example, you would modify `/etc/aliases` as follows:

```
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster@
postmaster: root@
nobody: root@
hostmaster: root@
usenet: root@
news: root@
webmaster: root@
www: root@
ftp: root@
abuse: root@
noc: root@
security: root@
root: christphe@, christophe.detroyer@gmail.com
```

I plan to log a bug/issue against msmtp to get this behavior changed so it just works and will update this answer then.

Comment: Wouldn’t the last line need to be `root: christphe@, christophe.detroyer@gmail.com`?

Comment: @Scott yes, it would.  Fixed now.

Comment: wait, why do you need two entries for the last alias?

Comment: @Gaia that was part of the question above. My guess is that wanted the emails to root to end up at his local mailbox on the server as well as on his isp mailbox.

Answer (score 6):

Found 2 things today on this when trying `msmtp` for the first time.

1. `/etc/aliases` default of `postmaster: root` gave things heartburn. Only revealed by `msmtp -v`

   - solved by changing line to `postmaster: root@somewhere.com`
2. put [`aliases /etc/aliases`](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/doc/msmtp.html#aliases) in `/etc/msmtprc` or `~/.msmtprc`

Answer (score 0):

> The next thing I want to configure is that my email for my root
>   account (e.g., output from crontabs) is sent to my isp email as well.

1. Add a line like this on `/etc/msmtprc`:

```
   aliases /etc/aliases.msmtp
```

2. Create the file `/etc/aliases.msmtp` that contains this line:

```
   default: christophe.detroyer@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

msmtp and AppArmor don't play well together. 
AppArmor was okay with msmtpd reading `/etc/aliases`
but balked at reading `/etc/aliases.msmtp`.

I found the problem by using the `-v` option of msmtp and sending a test mail.

I recommend sticking to `/etc/aliases`.